# Make my popup draggable anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

I have this popup window and I want to make it draggable. I searched everywhere for a solution but I couldn't find one that worked for me. I was wondering if someone can help me out? Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size
        var query = popURL.split('?');
        var dim = query[1].split('&');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({
            'width': Number(popWidth)
        }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"></a>');
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;
        //Apply Margin to Popup
        $('#' + popID).css({
            'margin-top': -popMargTop,
            'margin-left': -popMargLeft
        });
        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
        $('#fade').css({
            'filter': 'alpha(opacity=80)'
        }).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'})
        return false;
    });
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() {
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove(); //fade them both out
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#fade {
    display: none;
    background: transparent;
    position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: .80;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.popup_block{
    color: #000;
    display: none;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    float: left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 55%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
img.btn_close {
    float: right;
    margin: -20 -20px 0 0;
}
*html #fade {
    position: absolute;
}
*html .popup_block {
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you ever have the need to see it here's the [link](http://dvfw.tumblr.com/windows). Start --> Message

Comment: use jQuery UI Dialog

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery-UI, dialog box?

Comment: Since you already have jQuery loaded and in use, try using the draggable function https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ `$( "#draggable" ).draggable();`

Answer (score 0):

As the jQuery UI library is already loaded, the following code will make your popup block draggable:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popup_block').draggable();

  // ...
  // your code
}
</script>
```

See the documentation of the jQuery UI draggable widget for more information about available options: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

jQuery UI also offers demonstrations of several use cases: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/